# Show thumbnails of zipped images

Tags: windows-10, zip, thumbnails

I'm using Windows 10. I have a collection of zip files with JPG images. When I click on the zip file to view the contents, I would like to see a thumbnail of these images (even when I am in "Extra Large Icons" mode), but I only see a jpg icon.

If I unzip the file, then I can see the thumbnails.

Is it possible to adjust the windows settings so that thumbnails are shown without unzipping the file?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem. Would like to find a way to view the images stored in zip archives without unzipping them all.

Answer (score 3):

CBX Shell provides Windows Explorer thumbnail and infotip extensions for image archives. It enables thumbnail preview for ZIP, CBZ, CBR and RAR image archives. Windows Explorer will display a thumbnail image of the first photo in the archive instead of the generic archive icon.

- CBX Shell supports JPG, BMP, PNG, TIFF, GIF and ICO.
- works on Windows 2000 / XP / Vista / Win7/ Win10 (32 / 64-bit).
- ZIP64 archives are not supported.
- Thumbnail may not be displayed if the archive is damaged.
- Images larger than 32 MB are not displayed to avoid memory
  consumption.
- Encrypted ZIP and RAR archives can not display thumbnail.

[Download](http://free-sk.t-com.hr/T800soft/software/packages/CBXShell.zip)

[Project on GitHub](https://github.com/T800G/CBXShell)

Comment: This is false. All CBX Shell does is show the first image as the preview for that archive. All the files inside the archive are still just icons. But thanks for getting my hopes up and making me install this fairly useless piece of software.

Comment: **//thanks for getting my hopes up and making me install this fairly useless piece of software//**

whew! kinda harsh! ^_^ ...